# Splash background color Windows 8 Cordova Tools

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, ctp

I am using Visual Studio and the Cordova tools plugin. How can I change the background of the splash screen. The image provided does not cover the entire screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change setting on config.xml

```
<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xff0000ff"/>
```

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing This is a complete answer to my question.

Comment: Does this Change the Background Color of the whole application?

Comment: For anyone that finds this later, the hex color is in ARGB format, not RGBA

Answer (score 0):

Use this npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-splash you have to create one image that is 2208x2208 and it will generate all the required formats from that