# How to make UWP cordova app icon background to match windows theme

Tags: windows, cordova, uwp

The title says it all.

All images in the platforms/windows/images folder are png files with transparent background, but when I build the app package it becomes gray. Like in the image below.

Is there a way to make my cordova UWP app have a dynamic background that matches the windows theme just like "skype" does.

[image]

Files in platforms/windows/images directory

```
SplashScreen.scale-100.png
SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png
Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png
Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png
Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png
Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png
Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png
Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png
Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png
Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png
Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png
StoreLogo.scale-100.png
StoreLogo.scale-240.png
Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png
Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png
```

UPDATE:

After reading Dave Smits answer I realized that background color on start menu is defined in cordova generated .appxmanifest file. I edited it manually and changed the element *uap:VisualElements* attribute *BackgroundColor* to "transparent" and generated package had a background color of current theme as I asked.

Next step is to change that BackgroundColor property from cordova config.xml, because it will be deleted next time cordova decides to generate a new .appmanifest file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your manifest you define a color too; make this transparent too[image]

to do directly in cordava add this to your config.xml

```
<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xff0000ff"/>
```

Comment: Hi, i do not have a direct acess to the .appxmanifest file since this is a cordova project, but there is one generated by cordova in platforms folder. and there is an entry: <uap:VisualElements BackgroundColor="#464646" .. that could be it. But my changes will be deleted next time cordova decides to generate a new one

Comment: I am not experienced with cordova, but it seems your icons are defined in the config.xml so would expect the color there also https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html

Comment: +1 you took me on the right path, i'm looking for ways to set that attribute through cordova config right now.  I checked that page a few times already, but haven`t found anything about background icons. Only thing closest was "wp8/Background.png", but it did nothing to help my case.

Comment: i think this awnsers your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807491/splash-background-color-windows-8-cordova-tools

Comment: Yup, add that to the answer and it will be a complete answer, thank you :) i was initially looking in a wrong problem which was a property not the icons